# Является ли это сложноподчинённым предложением? Обособлять ли конструкцию с "как"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Я привык, что в литературе во фразе "**почувствовал как**" отсутствует запятая.

Но, как мне кажется, здесь напрашивается обособление (разделение части СПП): *Андрей почувствовал(,) как пошёл дождь(,) и укрылся за деревом.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Андрей почувствовал, как пошёл дождь, и укрылся за деревом.**

Я не могу придумать конструкции, чтобы "почувствовал, как" в подобных случаях правильно было бы писать без запятой. [Нацкорпус тоже не может](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=1&req=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform).
Единственный возможный случай написания без запятой, который мне приходит в голову, — это в контексте сказуемого: "Я, робот, впервые почувствовал как человек".

Comment: Спасибо. Получается, это просто ошибки (в том числе изданных книг). Кстати, у Рудакова помню ещё конструкцию вида "Я почувствовал как краснею", где не было запятой. Мне показалось, что она должна быть там обязательно, но почему-то снова была пропущена.

Comment: @Theej да, ошибки. Запятая перед "как" не ставится в совершенно определённом списке случаев: http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183, и "почувствовал, как краснею" при всём желании нельзя трактовать как один их этих случаев.