# Как правильно: "почувствовал, как пошел дождь" или "почувствовал, что пошел дождь"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, союзы

**Оба ли варианта верны,** какой из них и почему вам кажется **предпочтительнее?**

Я считала, что здесь правильно сказать так: "почувствовал, что пошел дождь", но потом решила проверить. Оказалось, что с разной частотностью используются оба союза (почувствовал что/как).

Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение.

Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, что запятая перед союзом ИЛИ в заглавии не нужна. У нас две записи заключены в кавычки, их связывает одиночный союз ИЛИ.

Comment: По-моему, запятая не нужна ещё потому, что предложение вопросительное.

Comment: Посмотрите шестой подпункт третьего пункта в словаре Кузнецова: https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/как

Comment: А дальше что?  В Нацкорпусе союз "что" в этом СОЧЕТАНИИ встречается в 5 раз чаще, потому что он нейтральный, а "как" – особенный. А у всех, как оказывается, разница между ними стерлась, на что я никак не рассчитывала. Даже хотела замечание участнику сделать, что он не тот союз использовал.

Comment: Может, вам не нравится, что здесь подходит "каким образом".

Comment: Не нравится!  Я просто  реально слышу это. И как это вы догадались?  Союз КАК описывает реальные ощущения, например: чувствую, как постепенно намокает куртка.

Comment: Просто люблю локализовывать причины незвучания, это помогло сделать предположение. А у меня получается и по-другому воспринять. Просто надо прочитать "как" очень быстро и без малейшего ударения. Здесь два варианта восприятия. Могу предположить, что синонимичность союзу "что" возникла под влиянием народной речи.

Comment: В умной книжке я прочитала вот что: КАК – это чистое восприятие с помощью органов чувств, а ЧТО – это восприятие с последующим мысленным анализом  (ощущаю/вижу признаки дождя и делаю вывод).

Comment: Но в примерах Кузнецова такое же. А во втором примере тоже двусмысленность: *Я не заметил, что / каким образом ты вошёл.*

Comment: Не одно и то же.  В первом случае он вошел тихо, незаметно, а во втором случае просто вошел (отмечено как факт).  Разве не так?

Comment: Ну да, разные вещи. Он мог и через окно войти.

Comment: Мог и через окно войти или прокрался через дверь, какая разница.  Здесь подходит союз КАК, потому что "не заметил".  Как носитель языка, вы должны чувствовать разницу.

Comment: Честно говоря, везде вижу разницу.

Comment: Тогда я надеюсь, что будете употреблять союзы правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что "почувствовал, к**а**к пошёл дождь" отвечает на вопрос "как именно пошёл дождь", а "почувствовал, что пошёл дождь" — это ответ на вопрос "что произошло". Возможно, вследствие синонимичного употребления "что" и "как" в подобных конструкциях разница стёрлась. Лично я вообще стараюсь обходиться двоеточием: "Я почувствовал: пошёл дождь".

*P. S. С точки зрения писательского мастерства "чувствительные" и "мыслительные" глаголы лучше вообще использовать по минимуму. Это называется "глубокая позиция", в отличие от "фильтрованной". Сравните:*

- *Фильтрованная:*

> Такой клинок королю под стать, подумал Зигфрид. Он протянул руку и
> погладил сталь. Она была на ощупь скользкая, лезвие неощутимое.
> Зигфрид почувствовал, как под кожей у него забегали мурашки.

- *Глубокая:*

> Такой клинок королю под стать! Зигфрид протянул руку и погладил
> сталь. Скользкая, лезвие неощутимое. Под кожей у него забегали
> мурашки.

Comment: 1. Спасибо за ваше мнение.  К сожалению, вы не сделали выбор для моего предложения (вернее, это предложение было в недавнем вопросе). Так какой союз вы выбираете, ЧТО или КАК (без теории, по слуху, лично вы).  2. Двоеточие  –   это, как я думаю, не лучший выбор (сильный знак, да и подходит не всегда).

Comment: 3.  О писательском мастерстве. Мысль мне понятна, вот только терминология странная (искусственная какая-то).  Мне нравится ваша "глубокая позиция», но  прием этот известен со времен Пушкина и Достоевского – думаю, что предложение записано в стиле "несобственно-прямой речи". Такая  «локальная» запись смотрится довольно эффектно. (Но это, конечно, же всего лишь мнение дилетанта по части писательского мастерства.)

Comment: @Sharon вариант я выбирать не стану :) Что касается несобственно-прямой речи, то там ещё и, так сказать, 'несобственно-прямое' описание ощущений, то есть без глаголов 'увидел', 'почувствовал' и т.п.

Comment: Почему вы не хотите выбирать, мне понятно. Психология, психология... Может быть, еще кто-нибудь выберет, как вы думаете?  Вдруг найдутся люди, у которых разница между союзами еще не стерлась. Несобственно-прямая речь – это и есть "несобственно-прямое' описание ощущений"

Comment: @Sharon да, действительно, это несобственно-прямая речь. Я немного иначе этот термин понимал, то есть отчасти ошибочно.

Comment: Ну да, у нас тут даже конкурс был: надо было улучшить небольшой текст, применив там несобственно-прямую речь. Жаль, вас тогда не было.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ли почувствовать, что пошел дождь? Можно уловить в тишине (скорее почувствовал, чем услышал), различить в сумраке (скорее почувствовал, чем увидел). Ощущение наше тут же нам «объясняется» и нами понимается. Процесс краток, и нам мгновенно выдаётся ответ на все наши *что*, *где*, *когда*.

Но не на вопрос *как*: он не из области подсознательного. «Почувствовал, как пошёл дождь» — фраза из разряда просторечных. Союз *как* выступает здесь в значении *когда*.

Comment: Эм... а что, кожей нельзя почувствовать, что пошёл дождь? Одно из значений "почувствовать" в БТС — это "воспринять органами чувств, чутьём; ощутить".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я как раз на эту тему писала комментарий: КАК – это чистое восприятие с помощью органов чувств, а ЧТО – это восприятие с последующим мысленным анализом (ощущаю/вижу признаки дождя и делаю вывод).  Также помню известный пример: Я вижу, как белка прыгает по веткам. Союз ЧТО здесь плохо подходит, так как весь процесс воспринимается во времени (как видео).

Comment: @Nektoid В Ответе есть ответ: «Можно ли почувствовать, что пошел дождь? Можно...». Союз *как* к чутью имеет отношение, но не прямое.

Comment: @Sharon, Мы чувствуем, что кое-что случилось (кажется, пошел дождь)... Аналитики не вижу, только пища для неё. Видеть, как белка прыгает, — прямо получать знание и складывать в коробочку.

Comment: В грамматике написано: Союз КАК применяетс при опорных словах со значением восприятия, ощущения. Союз ЧТО является наиболее нейтральным. Это знание, полученное в результате восприяяти и интеллектуального анализа.  Поэтому в предложении   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470260/Является-ли-это-сложноподчинённым-предложением-Обособлять-ли-конструкцию-с-как   желательно использовать союз ЧТО.

Comment: Да, правда ваша! Хотя эта теория в конкретных случаях не идеальна, — контекст не позволяет. Для чистоты обсуждения вводная (предшествующая) фраза многое предопределила бы.

Answer (score -1):

```
Я сделал то, что должен.
Я сделал то, как должен.
```

в последнем предложении "как" служит для определения "то", по типу:

```
Я сделал то, какое должен
```

Да предложения не звучат, но они абсолютно верные.

Comment: Первое звучит, а во втором надо так: *Я сделал так, как должен.* Кстати, если не звучит, то уже не абсолютно верное.

Comment: Дизлайк не мой, не подумайте.

Comment: Дизлайк не мой, не подумайте.     Но это не тот тип предложения. Там изъяснительное придаточное, союзная связь, а здесь связь местоименная.

Comment: oleedd если не звучит, то надо просто подставить другие слова в ту же самую схему. Сама схема от этого не перестает быть верной, не говоря уже про абсолютно нормальное "То, как должен - я сделал". sharon ну в таких предложениях "то" часто опускается.

Comment: Но вы же не про схему говорили, а про предложения. Звучание (оно связано со стилистикой) — один из критериев абсолютной верности. *не говоря уже про абсолютно нормальное "То, как должен - я сделал"* — что-то не вижу в этом ничего нормального.